# View Controller loading from storyboard taking too much time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

In my application, I am having 5 viewControllers. In which I have 4 web services call. While going from 4th controller to 5th controller, there is no web service, Still taking so much time to load.

What could be the possible possible reasons?

My observation :

1. View controller is coming to viewDidLoad very late.
2. Storyboard should the issue.
3. Once I am removing custom fonts from some labels, it is working fine.

Comment: Possible reason could be that u are calling web service on 4 VC, where data s loading synchronously and when u move to 5 VC, it takes time due to data s not loading in other VC. Could u check with that.

Comment: maybe you can use instruments->time profiler to find the hot spot

Comment: @Imran I am not calling any webservice...Once I am removing custom fonts from some labels, it is working fine.

Comment: have same issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my case, the **font** assigned to control(s) was wrong.

`ProximaNovaSoft-Semibold` font was assigned to controls, but this font did not exist. The real font was `Proxima Nova Semibold`.

Because `ProximaNovaSoft-Semibold` did not exist, **the system took time to search for this font** causing a delay.

After I corrected the font for some of my controls, it loads fast.

Answer (score 2):

You can check against some potential cases:

1. In VC4, are you doing something in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`?
2. Make sure you are loading data asynchronously in VC4?
3. Are you doing something bulky in `viewWillAppear` in VC5?
4. If you go from VC1/2/3 to VC5, does it still take a lot of time?

Comment: Thanks for answer dude....1. Nothing happening in viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear 2. No synchronous data in VC4 3. Nothing in viewWillAppear.. Once I am removing custom fonts from some labels, it is working fine

Comment: Then, I believe loading and applying custom fonts are causing delay.

Comment: I found the solution.....there was some naming problem in font...thanks for answer